# How to tag and manage my manga comic collection?

Tags: software-recommendation, tagging

I have a large number of manga (Japanese comics) loosely organized in compressed folders per story, which I sorted into folders by the category of authors. Is there an application that could add tags to each story/compressed folder to indicate, for example, the manga's genre (romance, drama, tragedy, adventure) so if I want to search for manga which have adventure I can easily find them?

Particularly, is there an application which has a GUI and is not run in the terminal? I'm not that good at using terminal commands.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is very specifically about comics, there are really two graphical applications in the repositories called `calibre` and `comix` that would be very useful to you.

You could manage all your comics in `calibre`, which has many more tagging and management features than `comix`, and then just use `comix` as the default viewer for your `.cbr` files. This would probably be the best of both worlds as both `calibre` and `comix` can read from archived tar and compressed zip folders.

If you create your library just with `comix`, it is possible to add comments per imported folder or comic, and then search throughout your library. If that is sufficient then you could just use `comix` for management and viewing, although `calibre` definitely gives your more options for tagging and managing your comics.

I note that you refer to manga comics, and `comix` has several features that support manga such as a setting to switch to right to left reading.

Screenshot featuring Comix with a sample Marvell (tm) comic:

[image]